# NotebookEventAction that triggers AFTER two successive key presses (not one)

Tags: keyboard, notebooks

My notebooks contain only text-based cells and no code.  I use InputAliases quite a bit to save time.  Typing the escape key before and after to trigger the InputAliases is not very efficient for me.

I would like to build a NotebookEventAction that triggers when I type "s" and "/" successively.  This will work for me as it is rare that I would ever type these keys successively in my text-based notebooks.

I have successfully built the action to trigger when I type the "s" as shown below.  Works great.

```
SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], 
  NotebookEventActions -> {{"KeyDown", "s"} :> 
     KeyBindings`MySpecial[]}];

KeyBindings`MySpecial[] := Module[{},
   SelectionMove[InputNotebook[], All, Word];
   NotebookApply[InputNotebook[], 
    "\\[AliasDelimiter]\\[SelectionPlaceholder]\\[AliasDelimiter]"]];
```

However, I would like it to only trigger when I type "s" and then "/" in succession.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably have more luck using a modifier such as Control rather than tracking a two-key sequence.  However NotebookEventActions does not seem to support that.  A solution would be to add the modified key binding as a menu item, added to MenuSetup.tr

Something like this

```
Item["Special KeyBinding", KernelExecute[KeyBindings`MySpecial[]],
 MenuKey["s", Modifiers -> {"Control"}], MenuEvaluator -> Automatic]
```

based on the last item here: [How can I set a keyboard shortcut to run a command?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16174/363)

Of course, Control+s is generally used for Save so you'd probably want to use something different.  You might also need FrontEndExecute instead of KernelExecute.

Comment: Also interesting : [How can I customize my menus without reloading MenuSetup.tr?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/145920/363)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for successive keystrokes. This one triggers when I press "/" and then "s" in succession (the s is my moniker for shortcut).  I'm not great at writing code.  Maybe someone else can clean up my code below, but it does seem to work.  Notice, I temporarily created a NotebookEventAction inside of the other one and then reset it after so that the succession works.

To try it out, run the code below and then open a text cell and type "alpha.s"

```
Res := SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], 
   NotebookEventActions -> {{"KeyDown", "/"} :>
      
      MyBindings`MySpecial[]
     }];
Res[];
MyBindings`MySpecial[] := 
  Module[{}, 
   SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], 
     NotebookEventActions -> {{"KeyDown", "s"} :> {
         SelectionMove[InputNotebook[], All, Word];
         
         NotebookApply[InputNotebook[], 
          "\\[AliasDelimiter]\\[SelectionPlaceholder]\\[\
AliasDelimiter]"];
         Res[];
         }}];
   ];
```

Comment: +1 very clever. Something is weirdly breaking in the copy & paste to Mathematica though.  I got it working fine by copying in the complete NotebookApply expression from your original question section.

Comment: related... https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/265379/my-custom-shortcut-for-escape-key-is-not-parsing