# Where put or edit an init.m to add menu commands?

Tags: front-end, version-10, initialization, menu

In [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1606/how-make-addmenucommands-work-in-an-init-m), answers were given that worked to add items to some menu commands, e.g., additional colors on the Format > Background Color menu, or Help menu items. I have code for such in an `init.m`:

```
AddMenuCommands["OpenHelpLink",{Delimiter,
Item["Installed Add-Ons",FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`FrontEndToken["OpenHelpLink",    
   {"guide/InstalledAddOns",Automatic}]]],
Item["Standard Extra Packages",FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`FrontEndToken["OpenHelpLink",
   {"guide/StandardExtraPackages",Automatic}]]], Delimiter}];

AddMenuCommands["BackgroundDialog",{Delimiter,
Item["L&inen",Background->RGBColor[0.980,0.941,0.902]],
Item["A&liceBlue",Background->RGBColor[0.941,0.973,1.0]],
Delimiter,
Item["HelpBrowser Sand",Background->RGBColor[0.964706,0.929412,0.839216]],
Item["SlideShow Slate",Background->RGBColor[0.408011,0.440726,0.8]]
}];
```

The solution proposed [there](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1606/how-make-addmenucommands-work-in-an-init-m) was to place that `init.m` into:

`$UserBaseDirectory/Autoload/PacletManager/Configuration/FrontEnd/`

However, this no longer seems to work with Mathematica 10.0.1. Yes, I did restart with a clean cache and clean preferences.

I note that in `$UserBaseDirectory/Autoload/PacletManager/Configuration/FrontEnd/` there's already a file `init_10.0.1.0`. I even tried appending the code displayed above to that (and appending a semi-colon to the long `SetOptions[$FrontEndSession...` expression already in `init_10.0.1.0`, but still no change to the menus. Moreover, after I restart *Mathematica*, the added text has disappeared from `init_10.0.1.0`.

I'm using version-specific front end preferences, just as I had been doing with *Mathematica* versions 8 and 9.0.1, and, I think, version 10.0.0.

What am I doing wrong? How get this to work?

Comment: Have you ever obtained a satisfactory resolution of this issue?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I have a partial answer to my question. In order to add menu items, e.g., to submenus of the Format menu for *Mathematica* version 10.0.1.

**What to put in the `init.m`**

```
FrontEndExecute[
AddMenuCommands["BackgroundDialog",
{Delimiter,
MenuItem["Linen",Background->RGBColor[0.980,0.941,0.902]],
MenuItem["AliceBlue",Background->RGBColor[0.941,0.973,1.0]],
MenuItem["MintCream",Background->RGBColor[0.961,1.0,0.980]],
MenuItem["LightYellow",Background->RGBColor[1.0,1.0,0.878]],
MenuItem["Smoke",Background->RGBColor[0.961,0.961,0.961]],
Item["MistyRose",Background->RGBColor[1.0,0.894,0.882]],
Delimiter,
MenuItem["HelpBrowser Straw",Background->RGBColor[0.960784,0.878431,0.666667]],
MenuItem["SlideShow Slate",Background->RGBColor[0.408011,0.440726,0.8]]}]];

FrontEndExecute[
AddMenuCommands["FontColorDialog", 
{Delimiter, 
Item["HelpBrowser Brick", FontColor -> RGBColor[0.592157, 0.313726, 0.313726]],
Item["Mocha", FontColor -> RGBColor[0.501961, 0.25098, 0]],
Item["Ocean", FontColor -> RGBColor[0, 0.25098, 0.501961]],
Item["Eggplant", FontColor -> RGBColor[0.25098, 0, 0.501961]]}]];
```

This works despite the information from Wolfram tech support that this can no longer be done!

Note that it does *not* work if the wrapping function `FrontEndExecute` is removed (although in previous *Mathematica* versions `FrontEndExecute` was not needed).

**Where to put the `init.m`**

That `init.m` will work if it's placed in `$UserBaseDirectory/Autoload/FrontEnd`.

However, it does *not* work if the same `init.m` is placed, instead, in 
`$UserBaseDirectory/Autoload/PacletManager/Configuration/FrontEnd`(which did work with previous *Mathematica* versions).

**The remaining problem**

What remains to be done is how to get the Help menu additions to work that were indicated in the original question.

A possible clue: in the system file `MenuSetup.tr` that, the Format and most other main menu items use the function `Menu`, but the item for the help menu uses instead the function `HelpMenu`.

Comment: I tried this on my machine, but unsuccessfully. It is strange. Instead I succeeded to install it into `$InstallationDirectory/SystemFiles/Autoload/PacletManager/Kernel `. This is already the second case when on my machine I cannot work with the init.m file where other people seem to easily work with it, but secceed at the mentioned position. I have a question, however. In my case all the items are repeated twice in the Menu/Format/FontColor and Menu/Format/BackgroundColor. Do you know any reason?

Comment: @Alexei Boulbitch: The only reason I can think of for having items appear twice is that you have, in fact, two init.m's being read. I recommend against putting any files of your own, or editing any, in the `$InstallationDirectory` tree, if for no other reason than that they'll disappear whenever you upgrade with a new *Mathematica* version.

Answer (score 0):

I never did what you are trying to do. However, I added an add-on to the init.m file in order to always load it up together with Mma. I used then the init.m file situated here:
`~\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\10.0\SystemFiles\Autoload\PacletManager\Kernel`. 
May be you could try this. Please let me know, if you succeed.

Comment: @Alexi Boulbitch: Unfortunately, doing that does not allow the kernel to start at all for me. (I was surprised you gave directory starting at path `~\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\10.0\SystemFiles\`, since my Mathematica.app is in `\Applications`. By any chance, did you mean to put the edited `init.m` in `Library\Mathematica\SystemFiles\Autoload\PacletManager\Kernel`?)

Comment: @murray No, not into Library. The complete path on my machine looks as follows: `D:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\10.0\SystemFiles\Autoload\PacletManager\Kernel\init.m `. This is dictated by the fact that I installed Mma on the disk D. I did not use it, however, for the task you have in mind. My aim was to provide loading of one of the packages together with Mma, since I use this package on the everyday basis. It works for me.

Comment: I'm using OS X, not Windows. If I correctly translate what you're saying, you put the edited `init.m` into `$InstallationDirectory/SystemFiles/Autoload/PacletManager/Kernel`. If I do that, *Mathematica* hangs as soon as the Welcome splash screen appears.

Comment: @murray Yes, I checked `$InstallationDirectory `and it, indeed, gives the directory I used.

Comment: And editing the init.m so as add my AddMenuCommands there expressions (in separate initialization cells) locks up Mathematica. I need to force quit it, then remove the apparently offending code from `/Applications/Mathematica.app/SystemFiles/Autoload/PacletManager/Kernel/init.m`.

Comment: Just to check, does the `init.m` file you're editing contain merely the following: `Get["PacletManager\`PacletManager\`"] `?

Comment: @murray Before I changed it, it contained only this: `Get["PacletManager`PacletManager`"] ` Now it also contains `<<Presentations` `in another cell.

Comment: Right, as distributed, they init.m contains only `Get["PacletManager\`PacletManager/`"]`. I do note that loading an add-on such as *Presentations* would be a kernel activity, whereas adding items to the *Mathematica* system's menus would seem to be a front end operation.

Comment: I just received an answer from Wolfram Support about the question: "[According to the front-end developers,] it appears that package and functionality has been removed from the program. It was never a support functionality so doubt it will reappear. Based on what I see in your examples it appears you would accomplish much of the same by adding a new environment to your style sheet that would include a toolbar with links and paste buttons." Alas! But not sure which package "that package" refers to.

Comment: @murray Thank you for having informed me.

Comment: More bad news: it seems that now editing `MenuSetup.tr` in `$InstallationDirectory/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/Macintosh`no longer works to add menu items, either. (After restarting *Mathematica* 10.0.1 with a clean cache via Shift + Cmd.)