# Fraction shortcut does not work, KeyEventTranslations.tr gets ignored

Tags: front-end, linux, customization, keyboard

The fraction shortcut is not working.

Any change in my file `KeyEventTranslations.tr` in my directory `/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.3/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/X` gets ignored.

How to (possibly) reproduce it:

1. Go to

   ```
   FileNameJoin[
     {$InstallationDirectory, 
      "/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/X/KeyEventTranslations.tr"}]
   ```
2. Do ANY change and save the file. For example: Make a `"` in the beginning of the file or change

   ```
   Item[KeyEvent["Up"], "MovePreviousLine"], 
   Item[KeyEvent["KP_Up"], "MovePreviousLine"], 
   Item[KeyEvent["Down"], "MoveNextLine"], 
   Item[KeyEvent["KP_Down"], "MoveNextLine"],
   ```

   to

   ```
   Item[KeyEvent["Up"], "MoveNextLine"], 
   Item[KeyEvent["KP_Up"], "MoveNextLine"], 
   Item[KeyEvent["Down"], "MovePreviousLine"], 
   Item[KeyEvent["KP_Down"], "MovePreviousLine"],
   ```
3. Open *Mathematica* 10.3 and see if anything changed.
4. In my case nothing changes. There is no reaction to any change I do.

I'm using *Mathematica* 10.3 on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS and this file of `KeyEventTranslations.tr` is the only one on my harddrive.

How can that be and what can I do to make it work?

Comment: If it helps, I'm happy to provide you with further information.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Without further information nobody will be able to answer this. Also, changes to this file definitely have an effect and are not ignored.

Comment: @sebhofer What further information do you need?

Comment: @Karsten7. Mathematica does not react to any change. I for example changed the enter with the up arrow and everything stayed as it was. It is not a question about how to change something but a question about why everything I change gets ignored. There is something fishy going on and I have no clue how to find out what exactly it is.

Comment: @Karsten7. Yes this file. And it is unimportant what change I make. Every change gets ignored.

Comment: [This answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/68871/18476) might provide an useful alternative.

Comment: @sebhofer I can confirm issue.  Here is a workaround http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1606/how-make-addmenucommands-work-in-an-init-m

Comment: Did you try to make any other changes than to the `"Up"`/`"Down"`keys? I highly doubt that you claim that Mathematica does not react to _any_ change is correct. I certainly know you can customize the keybindings, also in version 10.3. I can confirm the issue with the cursor keys though.

Comment: I can confirm the issue: from 10.3 on, the custom shortcuts in KeyEventTranslations.tr are not taken into account. It was OK up to v 10.1 I think...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix that worked in my case:

1. Open **MenuSetup.tr**
   (in my case, on Linux, it was in
   /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.3/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/X/MenuSetup.tr)
2. Change

`MenuItem["&Fraction", "Fraction", MenuKey["/", Modifiers->{"Control"}]],`

to (add `,"Shift"`)

`MenuItem["&Fraction", "Fraction", MenuKey["/", Modifiers->{"Control","Shift"}]],`

3. Restart Mathematica

Comment: Thanks for your hint. It works also for me Mathematica 10.2 Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.