# Installing a Custom MenuItem into Init File

Tags: keyboard, menu

I have created a MenuItem that switches Wholecellgroupopeners On and Off for the currently selected notebook using the Control+w shortcut.

```
FrontEndExecute[
 FrontEnd`AddMenuCommands["DuplicatePreviousOutput", {Delimiter,
   MenuItem["WholeCellGroupOpener",
    FrontEnd`KernelExecute[
     SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], 
      "WholeCellGroupOpener" -> ! 
        CurrentValue@
         Options[SelectedNotebook[], "WholeCellGroupOpener"]]], 
    MenuKey["w", Modifiers -> {"Control"}], 
    System`MenuEvaluator -> Automatic]}]]
```

It would like to install this MenuItem in the FrontEnd so that it's installed at every startup.  I can't seem to make it work.  The MenuItem never shows up.  From other posts that I am reading it seems that I need to:

1. Save this as an init.m file and
2. Place it somewhere in the startup path

I tried and failed.  Can you help me?  Maybe I'm not saving the file as a init.m file correctly.  Do I need to use Xcode?  Also, where is the best place to store the init.m file?

Can I store it somewhere in the user/library/mathematica/ path or does it need to go in the path Applications/Mathematica/Content/ path?  I would prefer the former.

Comment: Is this the answer  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1606/5478?

Comment: But maybe better to edit MenuSetup.tr directly since it is meant to persist?

Comment: I didn't see that!  Thank you.  I'm confused.  Doesn't placing the init file in the right place make it permanent?

Comment: It does, it is 'here is a menu layout to use vs. modify default menu each time you launch'.