# How do I programmatically add to contextual menus?

Tags: front-end, customization

To programmatically add to menus you can do as described here:

[How do I add new menuitems to menus?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/907/how-do-i-add-to-menus)

What can I do to programmatically add to contextual menus? Is something similar to `AddMenuCommands` available?

Answer (score 11):

There's an option `ContextMenu`, which you seem to be able to set at cell, notebook, or even box level. They all default to something like

```
FEPrivate`FrontEndResource["ContextMenus", "something"]
```

That info seems to be in the ContextMenus.tr file in the `$InstallationDirectory`, SystemFiles, FrontEnd, TextResources.

In any case, all that that option needs is a list of `MenuItem[...]`. You can look at that file (or at MenuSetup.tr) to get a hang on the syntax. Then it's just setting the option.

Apart from the brute force method of reading the file, creating your own, adding your Menus, and setting that option, I still haven't found a way to "append" the MenuItems. Only to replace... I'll edit if I find something

Comment: You're right...you can't append menu items.  But you missed a second source of context menus...the `ComponentwiseContextMenu` option.  `ContextMenu` is used where you can easily dictate context menus by style, whereas `ComponentwiseContextMenu` allows you to determine context menus which belong to certain box types, the various cell-related widgets, etc., which may be difficult or impossible to apply styles to.

Comment: @JohnFultz Would you have some hints about getting context menus to show up in specific graphics elements in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/272307/2048)?