# Is mathematica's right click menu customizable to add Simplify tools?

Tags: front-end, simplifying-expressions, customization, menu, docked-cell

Mathematica provide `Algebraic Manipulate` palette for simplifying expression. But the palette window will always stay on top, which is quite annoying.

**Is is possible to customize mathematica's right click menu to add frequently used Simplify tools?** In this way we can first select expressions, then right click on it and select simplifying operation. I think this is handier than palette.

Comment: it doesn't answer your question at the end but shows the way: [How do I programmatically add to contextual menus?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2185/5478)

Comment: You can make that palette non-floating using `SetOptions[First@Notebooks["AlgebraicManipulation"], WindowFloating -> False]`.

Comment: @Karsten7. Sorry for the late reply. Actually, when it is non-floating, it is another kind of annoying when using the palette : )

Comment: @Kuba Thank you, Kuba. After reading that, still can't get it. Manipulating front-end option is still too complicated for my ability right now, sigh...

Comment: So you want [something like this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/57469/18476), but for the commands of that palette? Do you really want to have all commands? The menu will get cluttered. To you want the same behavior as the palette has? Especially the in place evaluation is a questionable feature.

Comment: If it's just about the fact that a palette is inconvenient, floating or not, than converting the palette into a [`DockedCells`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DockedCells.html) could be another alternative.

Comment: @Karsten7. I found both of your suggestion are appealing to me. And for the "menu will get cluttered. " problem, I think same kind of functions could be secondary menu list.

Comment: @Karsten7. and I really don't know how to make dockedcell work as a simplifying button after I tried it

Comment: @Karsten7. `DockedCells` always have to create a new window?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Adding the functionality of the Algebraic Manipulate palette to the context menu ("right click menu") of *Mathematica*

The commands of the Algebraic Manipulation palette are converted into `MenuItem`s, that will mainly use the `FrontEnd`, with

```
MenuItem[#[[1, 1]], FrontEndExecute[{
      FrontEnd`NotebookApply[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], #, All], 
      FrontEndToken["Evaluate"]}]] & /@ 
  Import[FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "Palettes", 
      "Other", "AlgebraicManipulation.nb"}]][[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, All, 1, 1]] // InputForm
```

One can switch to Full Screen by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> and back again with <kbd>F12</kbd>, to make sure the output is formated in a way that is convenient for the next steps. If, for example, ones monitor is to small, one can Copy As ► Plain Text the output and add the line breaks manually later.
In both cases any `ManuItem` one doesn't want to have in the context menu should be removed from the outputted list.

The content of the context menu is specified in the file

```
FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "TextResources", 
  "ContextMenus.tr"}]
```

This file can be edited with an editor (e.g. Notepad++), but a backup copy should be created first.

To open this file from within *Mathematica*

```
SystemOpen@
 FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "TextResources", 
   "ContextMenus.tr"}]
```

can be used.

The context for inputs starts with `"Input" -> {`.
To add a new menu entry after the entries related to `Evaluate`

```
Menu["&Algebraic Manipulate",
        {

        }],
        Delimiter,
```

can be copied into a new line created after the `Delimiter` of that section.

Now one only has to replace the created empty list with the list of `MenuItem`s constructed from the palette entries, save the *ContextMenus.tr* file and restart *Mathematica*.

[image: ScreenDemonstrationGIF]

Comment: But there seems an error in the column version, since directly copy as plain text have no commas between each `MenuItem`, if we pasted it directly into `ContextMenus.tr`, mathematica is unable to start

Comment: @matheorem Thanks for pointing that out. I removed the column version, as it is more error-prone and presumably not really helpful.

Answer (score 11):

Converting the Algebraic Manipulation palette into a [`DockedCells`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DockedCells.html):

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], DockedCells] = 
  Append[MapAt[Partition[Flatten[#], 9] &, 
    Import[FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "Palettes", 
        "Other", "AlgebraicManipulation.nb"}]][[1, 1]], {1, 1, 1}], 
   ButtonBoxOptions -> {BaseStyle -> "Evaluate"}];
```

[image]

This `DockedCells` can be customized further. For example, if you only need two buttons `Expand` and `Simplify`, then Change `Partition[Flatten[#], 9] &` to `{Flatten[#][[{1, 8}]]} &` to select only the first and 8th button for the dock.

Comment: You are awesome! This implementation is really great ! I accept your answer. BTW, would you like to add a right click menu version? I know you also have experience on this kind of implementation. That will make the answer complete. : )

Comment: @matheorem I added a right click menu version as another answer, as I'm having some ideas on how to improve this `DockedCells` that I may add to this answer together with some explanations some time.

Comment: As I said before, I wish I could accept both answer. But now I decided to accept your "right click" version, since it works great and is what I exactly asking for in the question. I hope you don't mind about this. Finally, I am really looking forward to your newer version of `DockCells` in the future : )