# Context menu to graphics component

Tags: graphics, front-end, undocumented, eventhandler

How do I add individual context menus (shown upon secondary mouse click) to various components of a graphics object without needing to go into edit mode?

Consider the following example:

```
Graphics[{Style[Disk[{0, 0}], 
   ContextMenu -> {
      MenuItem["Color", KernelExecute[Print[Black]], MenuEvaluator -> Automatic], 
      MenuItem["Shape", KernelExecute[Print["Circle"]], MenuEvaluator -> Automatic]}],
    Red, Style[Disk[{1, 1}],
   ContextMenu -> {
      MenuItem["Number 1", KernelExecute[Print[1]], MenuEvaluator -> Automatic], 
      MenuItem["Number 2", KernelExecute[Print[2]], MenuEvaluator -> Automatic]}]}]
```

Right clicking on the output graphics object does not trigger the appropriate shape-dependent context menu.  Instead I get the built-in context menu associated with the whole graphics object:

[image]

Instead, I have to go into graphics edit mode by double-clicking before right clicking correctly produces the appropriate context menu.

[image]

What do I need to do produce the correct context menu based on the mouse positioned over the appropriate shape without requiring me to go into edit mode?  The solution should work when `Deploy` is applied to the whole `Graphics`.  Further, I need it so that right-clicking outside either shape should not trigger the built-in context menu, and should not produce any menu at all.  Undocumented solutions especially involving `"EventHandler"`, `` FE`Evaluate ``, ... and friends are welcome.

Comment: Addendum: In my head the ideal solution would look like *the effect of* `EventHandler[..., {"MouseClicked", 2}:> (show context menu)]`, even if this exact approach is unavailable.

Answer (score 5):

This is likely cheating. It simulates a context menu with a palette. But there are no menus shown outside the disks and it works in a Deployed cell. Note that the `Which` goes throught the graphics elements from last to first drawn so that when there is an overlap we get the menu for the top element. The result of clicking in the palette menu is given in a `MessageDialog`.

```
CellPrint[
 ExpressionCell[
  Graphics[{Yellow, d1 = Disk[{0, 0}], Red, d2 = Disk[{1, 1}]}],
  "Output",
  CellEventActions -> {{"MouseDown", 2} :>
     (Which[
       RegionMember[d2, MousePosition["Graphics"]], NotebookClose[p]; 
       p = CreatePalette[{
          
          Button[Style["Number 1", FontSize -> 20], 
           MessageDialog["1"]; NotebookClose[EvaluationNotebook[]], 
           Appearance -> "Frameless"],
          
          
          Button[Style["Number 2", FontSize -> 20], 
           MessageDialog["2"]; NotebookClose[EvaluationNotebook[]], 
           Appearance -> "Frameless"]
          }, WindowSize -> {150,All}, 
         WindowMargins -> {{MousePosition[][[1]], 
            Automatic}, {Automatic, MousePosition[][[2]]}}, 
         WindowTitle -> "The red disk", TextAlignment -> Center],
       
       RegionMember[d1, MousePosition["Graphics"]], NotebookClose[p]; 
       p = CreatePalette[{
          
          Button[Style["Color", FontSize -> 20], 
           MessageDialog[Yellow]; NotebookClose[EvaluationNotebook[]],
            Appearance -> "Frameless"],
          
          
          Button[Style["Shape", 20], MessageDialog["Circle"]; 
           NotebookClose[EvaluationNotebook[]], 
           Appearance -> "Frameless"]
          }, WindowSize -> {150,All}, 
         WindowMargins -> {{MousePosition[][[1]], 
            Automatic}, {Automatic, MousePosition[][[2]]}}, 
         WindowTitle -> "The yellow disk", TextAlignment -> Center]
       ]
      )}
  ]
 ]
```

Comment: Commendable effort, but sadly the end result is a bit too crude for me to use.  I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 5):

It is not perfect but maybe it fits your needs:

```
withContextMenu[menu : {__RuleDelayed}] := Function[expr, withContextMenu[expr, menu]]
withContextMenu[expr_, menu : {__RuleDelayed}] := EventHandler[
   expr,
   {"MouseClicked", 2} :> (
     AttachCell[
      EvaluationNotebook[],
      Framed[Column[KeyValueMap[menuItem, <|menu|>], Spacings -> 0], 
       ContentPadding -> False, FrameMargins -> 0, 
       FrameStyle -> GrayLevel@.8, Alignment -> Left],
      {Left, Top}, 
      Offset[MousePosition["WindowAbsolute"]*{1, -1}, 0], {Left, 
       Top},
      RemovalConditions -> {"MouseClickOutside"}]
     ),
   PassEventsUp -> False
   ];

menuItem // Attributes = {HoldRest}
menuItem[lbl_, action_] := 
 Button[lbl, action; NotebookDelete@EvaluationCell[],
  Appearance -> "Frameless", Alignment -> Left, 
  ImageSize -> {{80, 1000}, Automatic}, 
  Background -> 
   FEPrivate`If[FrontEnd`CurrentValue["MouseOver"], GrayLevel@.95, 
    GrayLevel@.9], FrameMargins -> {{20, 2}, {2, 2}}]


Graphics[
  Disk[] // withContextMenu[{1 :> Print[1], 2 :> Print[2]}]
, Frame -> True
, PlotRange -> 10
] // withContextMenu[{3 :> Print[3], 4 :> Print[4]}]
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) It probably would be better to attach the cell to the `EvaluationCell[]` instead of `EvaluationNotebook[]`, or even better to `BoxObject`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov maybe but it seems to ignore MouseClickOutside more often.

Comment: Very interesting to me is ``Background -> FEPrivate`If[FrontEnd`CurrentValue["MouseOver"], color1,  color2]`` because it does not use `Dynamic`.  Would you provide me links to some reading material about when I can directly use ``FEPrivate` `` functions?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by what `Dataset` seems to do, we can use a `Dynamic` context menu for the entire `Graphics` expression, and update it based on which element we're over:

```
Attributes[customContextMenu] = {HoldFirst};
customContextMenu[cmVar_, prim_, cm_] :=
 DynamicWrapper[
  prim,
  If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], cmVar = cm]
  ]

DynamicModule[
 {cm = {}},
 Style[
  Graphics[{
    {Transparent, 
     customContextMenu[cm, 
      Rectangle[ImageScaled@{0, 0}, ImageScaled@{1, 1}], {}]}, 
    customContextMenu[cm, 
     Disk[{0, 0}], {MenuItem["1", KernelExecute@1]}],
    Red, 
    customContextMenu[cm, 
     Disk[{1, 1}], {MenuItem["2", KernelExecute@2]}]
    }],
  ComponentwiseContextMenu -> {"GraphicsBox" -> Dynamic@cm}
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

As you can see, I use a `Transparent` `Rectangle` as the background which allows me to reset the context menu when the mouse is not over any of the disks.