# Best way to add KeyEvents and faster Quit

Tags: front-end, keyboard, customization

Many users have asked how to add `KeyEvent`s to speed/improve keyboard input. [This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/880/137) is just a random example. The technique is always the same. It requires that you *manually* modify `KeyEventTranslations.tr` (an important system file).

It always struck me as a bit odd that even power users propose to manually do this.
Surely this system file is loaded into *Mathematica* at the start of a session (or not?), so it is perhaps possible to *programmatically* add the necessary KeyEvents to an already running *Mathematica* session. Of course in this case the new key bindings will only be temporary, but this might even be preferable in some cases.

So the question is: is it possible to *programmatically* add the necessary `KeyEvent`s to an already running *Mathematica* session, without changing the `KeyEventTranslations.tr`?
Alternatively: can we program *Mathematica* to backup `KeyEventTranslations.tr` and programmatically modify it? I know this is possible, I just wonder if someone has done it.

And perhaps automatically reload the new version so that it takes effect right away?

---

**The art of Quitting.**

I take the occasion to post another item related to "saving keystrokes for your retirement":
It recently came to my attention that many/most users when they want to quit the kernel, type `Quit[]`.

Well...the good news are that you just need to type `Quit` (saving two keystrokes).

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/907/121

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This will add `Quit` to Control+Q (and Alt+V Q Q):

```
FrontEndExecute[
 FrontEnd`AddMenuCommands["MenuListQuitEvaluators",
  {MenuItem["AddMenu &Quit",
    FrontEnd`KernelExecute[ToExpression["Quit[]"]],
    MenuKey["q", Modifiers -> {"Control"}],
    System`MenuEvaluator -> Automatic]}]]
```

It only persists for the front end session.

Usually I keep the following in my KeyEventTranslations.tr file:

```
Item[KeyEvent["q", Modifiers -> {Control}],
    FrontEndExecute[
        FrontEnd`FrontEndToken[SelectedNotebook[], "EvaluatorQuit", Automatic]
    ]],
```

Comment: @IstvánZachar it works the same even if you do not put the AddMenu string. I took it off

Comment: I like the FrontEndExecute argument. TOTALLY undocumented, lol. Can the same thing be done with the KeyEventTranslations ? Perhaps with some equally undocumented AddKeyEvent command?

Comment: @ magma - setting key events is documented. See the help on `NotebookEventActions`.

Comment: There is no way to add/overload KeyEventTranslations programmatically, but as we're seeing here, there are other ways to achieve similar effects.

Comment: @magma are you referring to either the "AddMenu &Quit" or "MenuListQuitEvaluators" string because I am not experiencing what described currently?

Comment: @Liam I do not understand what is it that you are not experiencing. I just described the standard way to add shortcuts, menus, ect (modifying KeyEventTranslations.tr) and suggested a quicker way to exit Mathematica session

Answer (score 6):

Here is a way that avoids the sometimes buggy `` FrontEnd`AddMenuCommands `` and gives us better flexibility. It's based on what I did [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/133851/38205) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/145848/38205) to do effectively arbitrary menu edits and placed on GitHub [here](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-tools/blob/master/CustomKeyEvents.wl).

The basic idea is to make an entirely new menu for our menu bindings. I'll do this like so:

```
Get["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-tools/master/CustomKeyEvents.wl"];
AddKeyEvent["r", FontColor -> Red, "Modifiers" -> {"Option"}];
AddKeyEvent["r", FontColor -> Inherited, "Modifiers" -> {"Command", "Option"}];
```

And then if we look at our new menus:

[image]

Our events are bound and ready for use:

[image]

[image]

The code itself is actually pretty small, but the basic idea is just to edit the `Menu` expression that Mathematica is using and set a new one using `` FrontEnd`ResetMenusPacket ``

Comment: This is a great package. Thank you. But trying it I get two Shadow warnings. do you have an update? :FrontEnd`Paste::shdw: Symbol Paste appears in multiple contexts {FrontEnd`,System`}; definitions in context FrontEnd` may shadow or be shadowed by other definitions.

FrontEnd`Evaluate::shdw: Symbol Evaluate appears in multiple contexts {FrontEnd`,System`}; definitions in context FrontEnd` may shadow or be shadowed by other definitions.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Great package!  I'm also having trouble getting rid of those shadows. Strange... I don't see Paste[] used in the entire package so I'm not sure what to fix.