# Specifying shortcut without modifying KeyEventTranslations.tr

Tags: linux, keyboard

Until recently, I followed the suggestions(e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327411/is-there-a-way-around-using-and-for-part-in-mathematica) to introduce some new shortcuts. However, I moved to another place recently, and here I am not allowed to modify `KeyEventTranslations.tr` personally. (I am now a user of linux system)

To find an alternative solution, I encountered this post.
[Best way to add KeyEvents and faster Quit](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6224/best-way-to-add-keyevents-and-faster-quit)

In the selected answer, the author introduced a seemingly alternative way but honestly I don't quite understand what it does and how I revise it to meet my needs.

Can you show me some simple examples in this direction? Or, it would be great if you suggest another solution.

Comment: See also: [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/68864/customize-keybindings-without-modifying-files-in-the-installation-directory)