# Customize keybindings without modifying files in the installation directory

Tags: keyboard, customization

> I would like to know if I can modify key bindings without being able to modify the  KeyEventTranslations.tr in the installation directory.
>
> So maybe putting another one in my home dir and linking to it in some way?

I have the same question as [above](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2012/Jul/msg00296.html). The answer provided there seems not doable. Besides, I use Linux.

Comment: Yes, but I don't have direct experience so I won't write an answer. I believe you can just put another KeyEventTranslations in the correct place in `$UserBaseDirectory`.  Check how [this script by Rolf Mertig](http://www.mertig.com/s.m) does it.

Comment: This idea of putting a modified copy in the tight location was mentioned already some time ago by @rm-rf I think.

Comment: As @Szabolcs said just copy the file to `\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\TextResources\(your os)` in `$UserBaseDirectory` and make changes to that copy.  This also has the benefit of not being deleted or overwritten when you update *Mathematica*!

Comment: @Szabolcs Hello. I want to know if I change Mathematica 13 into 14(someday in the future), does the language in file KeyEventTranslations.tr still work? I mean, will there exists some cases that the function you used in the past does not work nowadays?

Comment: There's always a risk that future versions change something, but so far this technique has worked.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can see what can be done by running (maybe inspecting it in a browser first)

```
Get["http://www.mertig.com/shortcuts.m"]
```

This code will generate a modified copy of the default KeyEventTranslations.tr in :

```
   FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "TextResources",
                 Switch[$OperatingSystem, "MacOSX", "Macintosh", "Windows", "Windows", "Unix", "X"],
                 "KeyEventTranslations.tr" }]
```

If you want to get rid of the extra keyboard shortcuts, while retaining the original ones of course, just delete the file by :

```
DeleteFile[FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "TextResources",
                                        Switch[$OperatingSystem, "MacOSX", "Macintosh", "Windows", "Windows", "Unix", "X"],
                                        "KeyEventTranslations.tr"
                          }]
               ];
```

The code follows below. 
Some keyboard shortcuts (involving F4 and F6 keys) are not available on MacOSX, since that seems to be not possible on MacOSX. @jfultz: how would I do something like KeyEvent["\[ODoubleDot]", ...] on a german keyboard? I could not figure that out.

I would like to thank @kuba for inspiration and hints (like how to use "CellCount" to find out if the cursor is in between cells or inside a cell) and testing and comments. He also  [posted](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16697/is-there-a-shortcut-to-select-all-cells-above-the-current-cursor-position/55073#55073) a simpler version for "Evaluate above", but I am a bit reluctant to use Experimental`FromCellIndex.

```
(* ::Package:: *)

(* ::Title:: *)
(*Shortcuts  Version 1.0.3*)


(* ::Subtitle:: *)
(*Date: December 12, 2014*)


(* ::Subsubtitle:: *)
(*Author: Rolf Mertig, http://mertig.com*)


(* ::Text:: *)
(*This is an installer for extra shortcuts.*)
(*Either run it in a Mathematica 9 or 10 (use 10 if you have it) or run it evaluating:*)
(**)
(*Get["http://www.mertig.com/shortcuts.m"]*)
(**)
(*Then restart the FrontEnd and enjoy the new shortcuts.*)
(**)


(* ::Text:: *)
(* Note:  This code will generate two files:*)
(**)
(*   FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "TextResources",*)
(*                 Switch[$OperatingSystem, "MacOSX", "Macintosh", "Windows", "Windows", "Unix", "X"],*)
(*                 "KeyEventTranslations.tr" }]*)
(**)
(* and*)
(**)
(*   FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "TextResources",*)
(*                 Switch[$OperatingSystem, "MacOSX", "Macintosh", "Windows", "Windows", "Unix", "X"],*)
(*                 "joker.m"}]*)
(**)
(*If you already do have such a file, please back it up before running this code.*)
(**)
(*If you want to get rid of the extra keyboard shortcuts, while retaining the original ones of course, just delete the file by :*)
(**)
(*        DeleteFile[FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "TextResources",*)
(*                                        Switch[$OperatingSystem, "MacOSX", "Macintosh", "Windows", "Windows", "Unix", "X"],*)
(*                                        "KeyEventTranslations.tr"*)
(*                          }]*)
(*               ];*)
(**)


If[$VersionNumber < 9,
  Print["This code works only in Wolfram Mathematica 9 and higher."],

  Block[ {mykeyevents},
    mykeyevents = "

(* Minimize All windows *)
       Item[KeyEvent[\"m\", Modifiers -> {Command,Option}],
                     KernelExecute[Map[Function[FrontEndExecute[ {FrontEndToken[Slot[1], \"WindowMiniaturize\"]}]], Notebooks[]]]
                     , MenuEvaluator -> Automatic
           ],

       Item[KeyEvent[\"x\", Modifiers -> {" <> If[$OperatingSystem === "MacOSX", "Command" , "Control" ] <> ", Shift}],
                     KernelExecute[ NotebookDelete[ Cells[ SelectedNotebook[], GeneratedCell->True] ] ]
                     , MenuEvaluator -> Automatic
       ],

(* Quit the Kernel *)
" <> If[$OperatingSystem === "Unix", " " ,
      "Item[KeyEvent[\"q\", Modifiers -> {Control}],
                      KernelExecute[
                      Module[{enb = EvaluationNotebook[]},
                      (* https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6224/best-way-to-add-keyevents-and-faster-quit?rq=1 *)
                      If[ $VersionNumber < 10,
                          ToExpression[\"Quit[]\"]
                          ,
                         (* however, for unknown reasons the above crashes Mathematica 10; therefore: *)
                      SelectionMove[
                          NotebookPut[Notebook[{Cell[\"\<NotebookClose @ EvaluationNotebook[];
                                      SetSelectedNotebook[enb]; Quit[]\>\", \"Input\" ]},
                                      WindowSize -> {10, 10}, Saveable -> False, Editable->False,
                                      WindowMargins -> {{-500, -500}, {-500, -500}} ]
                          ],
                          All, Notebook
                      ];
                      FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken[FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[], \"Evaluate\"]];
                      ]]]
                      , MenuEvaluator -> Automatic
                 ]
 "]
        <>
        ",
(* Select all cells upwards from where the mouse is and evaluate those cells. *)
Item[KeyEvent[\"" <> If[$OperatingSystem === "Unix", ",", "PageUp"] <>
        "\", Modifiers -> {" <>
        Switch[$OperatingSystem, "MacOSX", "Command, Shift", "Windows", "Control, Shift", "Unix", "Command, Option" ] <>
        "}],
         KernelExecute[  (* in order not to pollute the global context: *)
          Module[{ System`gv`enb = EvaluationNotebook[],
                   System`gv`tag = StringJoin[\"tmp\", ToString[Round[AbsoluteTime[]/$TimeUnit]]],
                   System`gv`editable
                   },
                (* Remember: we need to program in kind of FullForm here ... : *)
                If[
                   And[(System`gv`enb =!= $Failed),
                        (*make sure there is at least one cell in the notebook: *)
                        Length[Cells[System`gv`enb]] > 0
                   ],
                System`gv`editable = ReplaceAll[Editable, Options[System`gv`enb, Editable]];
                SetOptions[System`gv`enb, Editable -> False];
               (*Iff the cursur is in between cells, move up one cell (with thank's to Kuba for the CellCount information) : *)
                If[CurrentValue[System`gv`enb, \"CellCount\"] === 0,
                   SelectionMove[System`gv`enb, Previous, Cell, AutoScroll -> False];
                ];
                (* Only go on if we are not at the top of the notebook: *)
                If[CurrentValue[System`gv`enb, \"CellCount\"] > 0,
                   (* add the unique tag to the last cell: *)
                   MathLink`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd`SelectionAddCellTags[System`gv`enb, {System`gv`tag}]];
                   (* and move to the top of the notebook: *)
                   SelectionMove[System`gv`enb, Before, Notebook, AutoScroll -> False];
                   (* on to the first cell *)
                   SelectionMove[System`gv`enb, Next, Cell, AutoScroll -> False];
                   (* add the cell tag to all cells up to the last one which we tagged above *)
                   While[FreeQ[ReplaceAll[CellTags, Options[NotebookSelection[System`gv`enb]]], System`gv`tag],
                         MathLink`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd`SelectionAddCellTags[System`gv`enb, {System`gv`tag}]];
                         SelectionMove[System`gv`enb, Next, Cell, AutoScroll -> False];
                ];
                (* select all cells with tag *)
                NotebookFind[System`gv`enb, System`gv`tag, All, CellTags, AutoScroll -> False];
                ];
                (* remove the tags *)
                MathLink`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd`SelectionRemoveCellTags[System`gv`enb, {System`gv`tag}]];
                (* evaluate the selection *)
                SelectionEvaluate[SelectedNotebook[]];
                SetOptions[System`gv`enb, Editable -> System`gv`editable];

            ]
            ]], MenuEvaluator -> Automatic
 ],

(* Evaluate Notebook *)
" <>
        If[$OperatingSystem === "Unix",
          "Item[KeyEvent[\"h\", Modifiers -> {Control}],\"EvaluateNotebook\"],"
          ,
          "Item[KeyEvent[\"h\", Modifiers -> {Control}],\"EvaluateNotebook\"],"
        ] <>
        "
(* Select all cells upwards from where the mouse is *)
Item[KeyEvent[\"Up\", Modifiers -> {" <>
        If[$OperatingSystem === "MacOSX", "Command" , "Control" ] <>
        ", Shift}],
         KernelExecute[  (* in order not to pollute the global context: *)
          Module[{ System`gv`enb = EvaluationNotebook[],
                   System`gv`tag = StringJoin[\"tmp\", ToString[Round[AbsoluteTime[]/$TimeUnit]]],
                   System`gv`editable
                   },
                (* Remember: we need to program in kind of FullForm here ... : *)
                If[
                   And[(System`gv`enb =!= $Failed),
                        (*make sure there is at least one cell in the notebook: *)
                        Length[Cells[System`gv`enb]] > 0
                   ],
                System`gv`editable = ReplaceAll[Editable, Options[System`gv`enb, Editable]];
                SetOptions[System`gv`enb, Editable -> False];
               (*Iff the cursur is in between cells, move up one cell (with thank's to Kuba for the CellCount information) : *)
                If[CurrentValue[System`gv`enb, \"CellCount\"] === 0,
                   SelectionMove[System`gv`enb, Previous, Cell, AutoScroll -> True];
                ];
                (* Only go on if we are not at the top of the notebook: *)
                If[CurrentValue[System`gv`enb, \"CellCount\"] > 0,
                   (* add the unique tag to the last cell: *)
                   MathLink`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd`SelectionAddCellTags[System`gv`enb, {System`gv`tag}]];
                   (* and move to the top of the notebook: *)
                   SelectionMove[System`gv`enb, Before, Notebook, AutoScroll -> True];
                   (* on to the first cell *)
                   SelectionMove[System`gv`enb, Next, Cell, AutoScroll -> False];
                   (* add the cell tag to all cells up to the last one, which we tagged above *)
                   While[FreeQ[ReplaceAll[CellTags, Options[NotebookSelection[System`gv`enb]]], System`gv`tag],
                         MathLink`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd`SelectionAddCellTags[System`gv`enb, {System`gv`tag}]];
                         SelectionMove[System`gv`enb, Next, Cell, AutoScroll -> True];
                ];
                (* select all cells with tag *)
                NotebookFind[System`gv`enb, System`gv`tag, All, CellTags, AutoScroll -> True];
                ];
                MathLink`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd`SelectionRemoveCellTags[System`gv`enb, {System`gv`tag}]];
                SetOptions[System`gv`enb, Editable -> System`gv`editable];
            ]
            ]], MenuEvaluator -> Automatic
 ],

(* Select all cells downwards from where the mouse is *)

Item[KeyEvent[\"Down\", Modifiers -> {" <>
        If[$OperatingSystem === "MacOSX", "Command" , "Control" ] <>
        ", Shift}],
         KernelExecute[  (* in order not to pollute the global context: *)
          Module[{ System`gv`enb = EvaluationNotebook[],
                   System`gv`tag = StringJoin[\"tmp\", ToString[Round[AbsoluteTime[]/$TimeUnit]]],
                   System`gv`editable
                   },
                (* Remember: we need to program in kind of FullForm here ... : *)
                If[
                   And[(System`gv`enb =!= $Failed),
                        (*make sure there is at least one cell in the notebook: *)
                        Length[Cells[System`gv`enb]] > 0
                   ],
                System`gv`editable = ReplaceAll[Editable, Options[System`gv`enb, Editable]];
                SetOptions[System`gv`enb, Editable -> False];
               (*Iff the cursur is in between cells, move down one cell (with thank's to Kuba for the CellCount information) : *)
                If[SameQ[CurrentValue[System`gv`enb, \"CellCount\"] ,0],
                   SelectionMove[System`gv`enb, Next, Cell, AutoScroll -> False]
                ];
                (* Only go on if we are not at the end of the notebook: *)
                If[CurrentValue[System`gv`enb, \"CellCount\"] > 0,
                   (* add the unique tag to the last cell: *)
                   MathLink`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd`SelectionAddCellTags[System`gv`enb, {System`gv`tag}]];
                   (* and move to the end of the notebook: *)
                   SelectionMove[System`gv`enb, After, Notebook, AutoScroll -> False];
                   (* on to the last cell *)
                   SelectionMove[System`gv`enb, Previous, Cell, AutoScroll -> False];
                   (* add the cell tag to all cells up to the first one which we tagged above *)
                   While[FreeQ[ReplaceAll[CellTags, Options[NotebookSelection[System`gv`enb]]], System`gv`tag],
                         MathLink`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd`SelectionAddCellTags[System`gv`enb, {System`gv`tag}]];
                         SelectionMove[System`gv`enb, Previous, Cell, AutoScroll -> False];
                ];
                (* select all cells with tag *)
                NotebookFind[System`gv`enb, System`gv`tag, All, CellTags, AutoScroll -> False];
                ];
                (* remove the tags *)
                MathLink`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd`SelectionRemoveCellTags[System`gv`enb, {System`gv`tag}]];
                SetOptions[System`gv`enb, Editable -> System`gv`editable];

            ]
            ]], MenuEvaluator -> Automatic
 ],

 Item[KeyEvent[\"Delete\", Modifiers -> { " <>
        If[$OperatingSystem === "MacOSX", "Control, Shift" , "Control, Shift" ] <> "}],
         KernelExecute[ Map[NotebookClose,
                               Select[Notebooks[],
                               Function[z, StringMatchQ[
                                                        ReplaceAll[\"WindowTitle\",NotebookInformation[z] ],
                                                        \"Untitled-*\"
                            ] ] ] ];
         ], MenuEvaluator -> Automatic
],
" <>
        If[$OperatingSystem === "MacOSX", "",
          "
        Item[KeyEvent[\"Delete\", Modifiers -> {Command, Option}],
         KernelExecute[ LinkClose[First[Links[]]]
         ], MenuEvaluator -> Automatic],

"] <>
        "
(* by rm-rf: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/automating-esc-esc-formatting/5215#5215*)
Item[KeyEvent[\"[\"(*]*), Modifiers -> {Control}],
        FrontEndExecute[{
            FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[],
                \" " <> "\\" <> "[LeftDoubleBracket]\", After]
        }]
],
Item[KeyEvent[(*[*)\"]\", Modifiers -> {Control}],
        FrontEndExecute[{
            FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[],
                \" " <> "\\" <> "[RightDoubleBracket]\", After]
        }]
],
Item[KeyEvent[(*[*)\"]\", Modifiers -> {Control, Command}],
        FrontEndExecute[{
            FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[],
               \"" <> "\\" <> "[LeftDoubleBracket]\", After],
            FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[],
               \"" <> "\\" <> "[RightDoubleBracket]\", Before]
        }]
],
(* for german keyboards, for Yves  *)
Item[KeyEvent[\"F4\"],
        FrontEndExecute[{
            FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[],
               \"" <> "\\" <> "[LeftDoubleBracket]\", After],
            FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[],
                \"" <> "\\" <> "[RightDoubleBracket]\", Before]
        }]
],

(* on Linux and  Windows: set WindowMargins -> 42 on the selected notebook *)
Item[KeyEvent[\"F6\"],
       FrontEndExecute[{FrontEnd`SetOptions[FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[],  Rule[WindowMargins, 42]]}]
],

(* the 'live' configurable joker keyboard shortcut: *)
Item[KeyEvent[\"" <> If[$OperatingSystem === "MacOSX", "d", "t"] <> "\", Modifiers -> {Control}],
        KernelExecute[{
          Function[
          If[ FileExistsQ[ Slot[1] ],
              Get[ Slot[1] ]
          ]][ FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, \"SystemFiles\", \"FrontEnd\", \"TextResources\",
                            Switch[$OperatingSystem, \"MacOSX\", \"Macintosh\", \"Windows\", \"Windows\", \"Unix\", \"X\"],
                            \"joker.m\"}] ]
        }],
  MenuEvaluator -> Automatic
],

(* edit 'live' configurable joker keyboard shortcut: *)
Item[KeyEvent[\"r\", Modifiers -> {Control}],
        KernelExecute[{
          Function[
          If[ FileExistsQ[ Slot[1] ],
              NotebookOpen[ Slot[1] ]
          ]][ FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, \"SystemFiles\", \"FrontEnd\", \"TextResources\",
                            Switch[$OperatingSystem, \"MacOSX\", \"Macintosh\", \"Windows\", \"Windows\", \"Unix\", \"X\"],
                            \"joker.m\"}] ]
        }],
  MenuEvaluator -> Automatic
],

" <>
        "
(* inspired by Kuba: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32340/evaluating-selected-expression-using-keyboard-shortcut/32341#32341*)
 Item[KeyEvent[\"" <> Switch[$OperatingSystem, "Windows", ",", "MacOSX", "PageDown", "Unix", "c"] <>
        "\", Modifiers -> {" <>
        Switch[$OperatingSystem, "MacOSX", "Command", "Windows", "Control, Shift", "Unix", "Command, Option"] <>
        "}
      ],
      KernelExecute[
          CreateDocument[
             Function[
             If[ Or[ MatchQ[Slot[1], _String],  MatchQ[ Slot[1], _RowBox] ],
             {
             Cell[ BoxData[Slot[1]],\"Input\"],
             ExpressionCell[ToExpression[Slot[1]],\"Output\"]
             },
             Cell[TextData[\"Please select an expression inside a cell.\"], \"Text\"]
             ]
             ][Replace[NotebookRead[FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[]  ], {} -> Null]],
             WindowSize->{Medium, FitAll}, WindowMargins -> {{Automatic,2},{Automatic,2}}, Magnification->1.5
     ]
    ], MenuEvaluator -> Automatic
 ],

" ;

    With[ {os = Switch[$OperatingSystem, "MacOSX", "Macintosh", "Windows", "Windows", "Unix", "X"]},
      Quiet@CreateDirectory@FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "TextResources", os}];
      Module[{
        mykeyeventtrans = FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "TextResources", os, "KeyEventTranslations.tr"}],
        myjokerfilename = FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "TextResources", os, "joker.m"}], keytext, mykeytext,
        myjokerdir
      },
        myjokerdir = DirectoryName[myjokerfilename];
        If[ FileExistsQ[mykeyeventtrans], DeleteFile @ mykeyeventtrans];
        If[ FileExistsQ[myjokerfilename], Quiet @ DeleteFile @ myjokerfilename];

        Export[myjokerfilename,
          "
(* Define your own shortcut definitions here, without restarting the FrontEnd.
   The action defined here is executed by Ctrl T (Windows / Linux)  or Ctrl D (MacOSX)
*)

(* uncomment an example below or add your own definitions, save this file without renaming it and use it directly *)

(* Example 1: copy the selection as LaTeX. Evaluating sel pastes the clipboard *)

(*
  FrontEnd`CopyToClipboard[FrontEnd`CopyAsTeX[]];
  (* and also function assignments: *)
  sel := Paste[];
*)

(* Example 2:  wrap selection in [ ] *)

(*
  NotebookApply[SelectedNotebook[], RowBox[{\"[\", \"\\[SelectionPlaceholder]\", \"]\"}], Before]
*)


",
          "Text", CharacterEncoding :> $CharacterEncoding
        ];

        (* start with the default one : *)
        CopyFile[FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "TextResources",
          os, "KeyEventTranslations.tr"}], mykeyeventtrans];

        keytext = Import[mykeyeventtrans, "Text"];
        (* and add our extra keyevents: *)
        mykeytext = StringReplace[keytext, "EventTranslations[{"(*]*) :> StringJoin["EventTranslations[{\n "(*]*), mykeyevents, "\n "]];
        (* make sure things work in Mathematica 9 and 10 :*)

        mykeytext =
            Composition[# <> "\n" &,
              Function[StringReplace[#, "Item[KeyEvent[\"" ~~ it_ ~~ "\", Modifiers" ~~ ( mo__ /; StringLength[mo] < 30) ~~ "\"Redo\"]" (*]*) :>
                  "If[$VersionNumber < 10, {}, Item[KeyEvent[" ~~ it ~~ ", Modifiers" ~~ mo ~~ " \"Redo\"]]" (*]*), 1
              ]
              ],
              Function[
                StringReplace[#, "Item[KeyEvent[\"Redo\"]"(*]*) -> "If[$VersionNumber < 10, {}, Item[KeyEvent[\"Redo\"]]" (*]*), 1 ]
              ]
            ] /@ ImportString[mykeytext, "Lines", CharacterEncoding :> $CharacterEncoding];
        Export[mykeyeventtrans, mykeytext, "Text", CharacterEncoding :> $CharacterEncoding];

        CellPrint[ExpressionCell[Column[{ "This code generated the files",
          ( Button[StringReplace[#, $UserBaseDirectory -> "$UserBaseDirectory"],
            CreateDocument[{ TextCell[ Import[#, "Text"]]}]
          ]&@ mykeyeventtrans
          ),
          "and",
          ( Button[StringReplace[#, $UserBaseDirectory -> "$UserBaseDirectory"], NotebookOpen[#]]& @ myjokerfilename)}], "Text", ShowStringCharacters -> False]];
        CellPrint[TextCell["After restarting the FrontEnd you can use the following extra keyboard shortcuts: ", "Text", FontWeight -> Bold]];
        With[{myjokerdir2 = StringReplace[myjokerdir, $UserBaseDirectory -> "$UserBaseDirectory"]},
          Switch[ $OperatingSystem,
            "Windows",
            CellPrint[TextCell[#, "Text", FontSize -> 14, ShowStringCharacters -> False]&@
                Grid[{

                  { "Ctrl Shift \[UpArrow] ", "Select all cells from the beginning of the notebook until the position of the mouse "},
                  { "Ctrl Shift \[DownArrow] ", "Select all cells from the position of the mouse until the end of the notebook "},
                  { "Ctrl Shift PageUp ", "Evaluate all cells from the beginning of the notebook until the position of the mouse "},
                  { "Ctrl Shift X ", "Delete all generated cells, like Output, Message and Print cells "},
                  { "Ctrl Q ", "Quit Kernel immediately (* flickers , but does not beep *)"},
                  { "Cmd Alt Delete ", "Quit Kernel immediately (* beeps, but does not flicker *)"},
                  { "Ctrl H ", "Evaluate Notebook"},
                  { "Ctrl Shift ,", "Copy/Evaluate/Paste the selected cell subexpression into a new notebook "},
                  { "Ctrl Shift X ", "Delete all generated cells, like Output, Message and Print cells "},
                  { "Cmd Alt M ", "Minimize all Mathematica notebooks "},
                  { "Ctrl Shift Delete ", "Delete all Untitled-*  notebooks without confirmation "},
                  { "F4 ", "Insert [[]]"},
                  { "F6 ", "Apply SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], WindowMargins -> 42]"},
                  { "Ctrl T ", "Evaluate the file joker.m from " <> myjokerdir2},
                  { "Ctrl R ", "Open joker.m from " <> myjokerdir2},
                  { Framed[
                    Style["The following three shortcuts work only on english keyboards: ", "Text"],
                    FrameStyle -> None, FrameMargins -> 10],
                    SpanFromLeft
                  },
                  { "Ctrl [ "(*]*), "Insert [["},
                  { (*[*)"Ctrl ] ", "Insert ]]"},
                  { (*[*)"Ctrl Alt ] ", "Insert [[]]"}
                }, Alignment -> {Left}, Dividers -> All, FrameStyle -> LightGray]
            ],

            "MacOSX",
            CellPrint[TextCell[#, "Text", FontSize -> 14, ShowStringCharacters -> False]&@
                Grid[{
                  { "Cmd Shift \[UpArrow] ", "Select all cells from the beginning of the notebook until the position of the mouse "},
                  { "Cmd Shift \[DownArrow]  ", "Select all cells from the position of the mouse until the end of the notebook "},
                  { "Fn Shift Cmd \[UpArrow] ", "Evaluate all cells from the beginning of the notebook until the position of the mouse "},
                  { "Cmd Shift X ", "Delete all generated cells, like Output, Message and Print cells "},
                  { "Ctrl Q ", "Quit Kernel immediately"},
                  { "Ctrl H ", "Evaluate Notebook  "},
                  { "Fn Cmd \[DownArrow] ", "Copy/Evaluate/Paste the selected Input cell subexpression into a new notebook "},
                  { "Cmd Opt M ", "Minimize all Mathematica notebooks "},
                  { "Fn Shift Ctrl Delete ", "Delete all Untitled-*  notebooks without confirmation "},
                  { "Ctrl D ", "Evaluate the file joker.m in " <> myjokerdir2},
                  { "Ctrl R ", "Open joker.m from " <> myjokerdir2},
                  { Framed[
                    Style["The following three shortcuts work only on for english keyboards: ", "Text"],
                    FrameStyle -> None, FrameMargins -> 10], SpanFromLeft
                  },
                  { "Ctrl [ "(*]*), "Insert [["},
                  { (*[*)"Ctrl ] ", "Insert ]]"},
                  { (*[*)"Ctrl Cmd ] ", "Insert [[]]"}
                }, Alignment -> {Left}, Dividers -> All, FrameStyle -> LightGray]
            ]
            ,
            "Unix",
            CellPrint[TextCell["Mod1 and Mod2 are usually the Windows Key and the Alt Key ", ShowStringCharacters -> False]];

            CellPrint[TextCell[#, "Text", FontSize -> 14, ShowStringCharacters -> False]&@
                Grid[{
                  { "Ctrl Shift \[UpArrow] ", "Select all cells from the beginning of the notebook until the position of the mouse "},
                  { "Ctrl Shift \[DownArrow] ", "Select all cells from the position of the mouse until the end of the notebook "},
                  { "Mod1 Mod2 , ", "Evaluate all cells from the beginning of the notebook until the position of the mouse "},
                  { "Ctrl Shift X ", "Delete all generated cells, like Output, Message and Print cells "},
                  { "Mod1 Mod2 Delete ", "Quit Kernel immediately"},
                  { "Ctrl H ", "Evaluate Notebook "},
                  { "Mod1 Mod2 C ", "Copy/Evaluate/Paste the selected Input cell subexpression into a new notebook "},
                  { "Mod1 Mod2 M ", "Minimize all Mathematica notebooks "},
                  { "Ctrl Shift Delete ", "Delete all Untitled-*  notebooks without confirmation "},
                  { "F4 ", "Insert [[]]"},
                  { "F6 ", "Apply SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], WindowMargins -> 42]"},
                  { "Ctrl T ", "Evaluate the file joker.m in " <> myjokerdir2},
                  { "Ctrl R ", "Open joker.m from " <> myjokerdir2},
                  { Framed[ Style["The following three shortcuts work only on for english keyboards: ", "Text"], FrameStyle -> None, FrameMargins -> 10], SpanFromLeft },
                  { "Ctrl [ "(*]*), "Insert [["},
                  { (*[*)"Ctrl ] ", "Insert ]]"},
                  { (*[*)"Ctrl Mod2 ] ", "Insert [[]]"}
                }, Alignment -> {Left}, Dividers -> All, FrameStyle -> LightGray
                ]]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
];
```

Comment: Nice work. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @belisarius De nada! I was just too much annoyed that some of my old shortcuts crashed Mathematica 10. Should I twitter the installation line?

Comment: I don't understand the choice of the name "joker" here.  Comment?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Well, you can change what Ctrl T does. Either it evaluates  (myInitVar=12;) or does something else. Whatever. And you can change it on the fly: Just hit Ctrl R : this opens joker.m in the FrontEnd. You uncomment an example or add whatever you like. Save it. Then, without restarting the FrontEnd you have redifined what Ctrl T does. That is like a joker (keyboard shortcut), isn't it?

Comment: Or, suppose you want to stack windows (not possible in V10.0.2 on Linux at all): just put     `FrontEndTokenExecute["StackWindows"]` in joker.m, hit Ctrl S (to save it; possibly followed by Ctrl W to close it), and then Ctrl T stacks them again.

Comment: Referring to [(73212)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73212/121) you might consider adding "move selected cells up" and "move selected cells down" shortcuts.

Comment: What's the key-code for an umlauted O on a German keyboard? I'm guessing you could supply that, much like this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/139748/38205

Comment: It's "\[ODoubleDot]". But I usually just do Esc o" Esc  to get \[ODoubleDot]

Comment: A *wild card* is any card that may be used to represent another card. In this case `joker.m` acts as a wild card :) (as you can emulate any keyboard shortcut by hitting Ctrl T) (Great package!)

Comment: This is ! I removed the space in the begin of: " \[LeftDoubleBracket]", After] and " \[RightDoubleBracket]" in the `KeyEventTranslations.tr`. Works like a charm in 12.1. Amazing.