# Add spaces to Mathematica comment delimiters?

Tags: front-end, customization, comment

Not exactly the world's most pressing problem, but one that has now exceeded my tolerance level. If I comment out a line of input such as

```
f[x_]:=x+1;
```

with Alt-/ (Windows), I get

```
(*f[x_]:=x+1;*)
```

But, as a believer in typographical as well as programmatic neatness what I really want is...

```
(* f[x_]:=x+1; *)
```

Just a space after the opening and before the closing...

How can that be done? Or would it spoil some vast eternal plan...?

Comment: Hi Julian, maybe it's too simple what I want to ask, but how do you (un)comment with the keyboard?  "Alt+/" doesn't seem to work... which keys do you press exactly?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea.Alt+/ has always worked for me (MMA 9-11.0.1.0, Windows) but care must be taken to ensure that the opening and closing brackets of (* *) are the 1st and last characters of the selection before typing Alt+/, otherwise MMA will not recognise the selection as a comment; I often end up re-commenting comments rather than uncommenting them for this very reason.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## New answer:

I updated my package to support not only templates but a menu with arbitrary actions so making an un/comment shortcut should be easier now.

Follow those steps:

1. [Install/update DevTools` v0.10.0+](https://github.com/kubaPod/DevTools)
2. Actions are available in `DevPackageDark.nb` stylesheet but you can make them work in any notebook by:

   ```
   Needs @ "DevTools`";
      (*Keep in mind it hijacks "Ctrl+," which stands for NewColumn *)
   NotebookActionsEnable[]
   ```
3. Open user actions file with `EditNotebookActions[]`
4. Put there a new item:

   ```
   <|"Label" -> "Un/Comment", 
     "ShortKey" -> "c", 
     "Action" :> Module[{foo, nb = EvaluationNotebook[]},
       foo[RowBox[{"(*", " ".., content_, " ".., "*)"}]]:=NotebookWrite[
         nb, content, All
       ];
       foo[RowBox[{"(*",  content_, "*)"}]]:=FE`toggleComment[];
       foo[boxes_]:= NotebookWrite[
         nb, RowBox[{"(*", " ",boxes, " ", "*)"}], All
       ];
       foo[$Failed|_CurrentValue]={};  

       foo @ CurrentValue[nb, "SelectionData"]
     ]

   |>
   ```
5. Click 'Save&Test'
6. You are ready to go with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> (NewColumn hijacked) followed by <kbd>c</kbd>

[image]

## OldAnswer:

You can use LiveTemplates [Live code templates](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/164653/5478).

- Go to a toolbar menu CodeTemplates > Edit User templates
- Add a new template:

  ```
  <|"Label" -> "(* ... *)", "Template" -> "(* `sel` *)", "ShortKey" -> "c"|>
  ```
- Save changes
- Use it with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> followed by <kbd>c</kbd>

[image]

---

Alternatively you can create a palette with something like this:

```
Button["c"
, NotebookApply[InputNotebook[]
  , RowBox[{"(*", RowBox[{" ", "\[SelectionPlaceholder]", " "}], "*)"}]
  ]
]
```

Or try to edit KeyEvenTranslations.tr file. Search around for guidelines but I find this method the least user friendly.

Comment: I now have devtools and some interesting extra capabilities to explore. I was reluctant to go that route at first, but I messed up the KeyEventTranslations.tr edits...  I'll see if I can work out how to remove this nicer bracket pair using your tools... MMA's "uncomment" of course leaves the extra spaces :) Thank you.

Comment: @JulianMoore Yes, it is tricky with .tr files. I will appreciate any feedback you have on DevTools, don't hesitate to create github issues or comment here. I am planning to add a similar feature but only with simple procedures you'd like to keep in a menu. Currently it is dedicated to applying templates so it may be quite tricky to abuse it to 'uncomment'.

Comment: @JulianMoore Please see the edit.

Comment: thx will check it out this w/e

Comment: Is it possible to use DevTools *without* having to use the dark mode you implement? (Contrary to what many programmers seem to prefer, these old eyes of mine find black text on a white, or light, background, much easier to use.)