# Is there any keyboard shortcut to delete the output of a particular cell

Tags: notebooks, customization, keyboard

Is there any keyboard shortcut key to delete the output of a particular cell in Mathematica.

Suppose if I am in a particular cell, and the cell has some output and If use some keyboard shortcut like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>, I should be able to delete the output of that particular cell.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is too much burden attached to working with `KeyEvenTranslations.tr` so I rarely use it.

You can try an alternative: [`` DevTools`:NotebookActions ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/184568/5478):

```
ResourceFunction["GitHubInstall"]["kubapod", "devtools"]
Needs @ "DevTools`";

NotebookActionsEnable[];

EditNotebookActions[];
```

add a cell with:

```
<| "Label" -> "ClearCell"
 , "ShortKey" -> "c"
 , "Action" :> FrontEndExecute[{
     SelectionMove[InputNotebook[],All,CellContents]
   , NotebookDelete @ InputNotebook[]
   }]
|>
```

Press **Save and Test**.

And you are ready to go: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> and then <kbd>c</kbd> should clear cell contents.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1964/58370). Change

```
FrontEnd`SelectionMove[FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[], All, Cell]
```

to

```
FrontEnd`SelectionMove[FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[], Next, Cell]
```

Comment: I did not get this, what exactly it does in a code?

Comment: As mentioned in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1977/58370)  answer. The shortcut definition has to be added to the file `KeyEventTranslations.tr`. Also mentioned in that answer is [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/880/58370) link which shows how to modify that file the right way. All the information you need is available in the links I have provided and the code modification in the answer above. Try it and if you are still unable to get it to work, add a comment and I will try to help out.