# Correct way to make groups of cells (not) evaluable

Tags: evaluation, cells, properties

Let us say that I want to make all the cells within a section not evaluable. In principle, I would simply highlight the relevant section, then go to `Cell -> Cell properties` and untick the `Evaluable`.
However, the problem is that if for some reason, I wish to make the section evaluable again, I would go back and tick the `Evaluable` box again. This, however, causes the section title and all the Texts within the section to also be evaluated, which of course is not what I want. When I toggle back the Evaluable, I would like it to do so only for the `Input` Cells of course. Is there to achieve this?

Comment: Is it satisfactory to enclose everything which you're not interested in evaluating in in a comment? Simply highlight everything you don't need to run and then either `Edit -> Un/Comment section` or just put comments over something you don't want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to re-enable it with `CurrentValue[_CellObject, Evaluatable] = Inherited`. You can create a custom palette:

```
CreatePalette @ Column[
  Button[
     StringForm["Evaluatable -> ``", #],
     CurrentValue[SelectedCells@InputNotebook[], Evaluatable] = #
  ] & /@ {False, Inherited}
]
```

Or you can use *notebook actions* analogously to https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/184568/5478

Comment: CurrentValue can be used to set all cells at once, so: `CurrentValue[SelectedCells @ InputNotebook[], Evaluatable] = False` is simpler.

Comment: @CarlWoll right, thanks, I forgot about that feature.