# In search of lost time: Mathematica keyboard shortcuts

Tags: front-end, undocumented, keyboard, user-interface

I am wondering about all the shortcuts that there are in Mma, besides the documented ones in https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/KeyboardShortcutListing.html.

Are there any undocumented ones? 
Is there a tutorial or document that gathers most of them?

For example, is there a keyboard shortcut for moving the cursor **at once** in the beginning/end of the cell if we are at some random point (of the same cell)?

Comment: In MacOS, you can hold Command and one of the arrow keys to go to the start or end of a line, just fyi. But that's an OS shortcut, not a Mathematica one, and I suspect many of the shortcuts you're looking for will be OS shortcuts rather than Mathematica ones.

Comment: Hey, that's nice! It seems that the same functionality is captured by the `Fn` key (at Linux at least).

Comment: Hopefully WRI will someday add vim bindings ;)

Answer (score 4):

(*feel free to contribute*)

- [Using the Mathematica front-end efficiently for editing notebooks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8310/5478)
- Adding new shortcuts / menu items / events:

  - [How can I set a keyboard shortcut to run a command?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16165/5478)
  - [Further examples in search results for `KeyEventTranslations.tr`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=KeyEventTranslations.tr)
  - [UserBase vs InstallationDirectory for modified resources](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/81016/5478)
- External solutions

  - Shortcuts`, package with custom shortcuts:
    [Is it possible to maintain user-defined shortcuts in a web-installable package?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/85823/5478)
  - DevTools`NotebookActions menu:
    https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/184568/5478