# How to define this useful shortcut?

Tags: performance-tuning, keyboard

My system of code organization in Mathematica is such that that after a block of code that achieves a specific goal I create a new cell and skip 4 or 5 lines in it, and write new code in the next line.

This is, of course, very messy -- but it would become much easier and more standardized if I could define a shortcut for it.

So is there a way for me to define a shortcut that

1. Creates a new cell;
2. Skips 4 lines and leaves the cursor on the fifth one.

Any advice is also appreciated.

Comment: There is probably a style for padding around cells. You could edit your style sheet to add padding above input cells. Then you wouldn’t need new lines at all.

Comment: `SelectionMove[InputNotebook[], After, Cell]; NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], StringRepeat["\n", 5]]` + https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/217028/5478

Comment: @lericr I had no idea about the style sheet. Could you point me to a reference on how to handle setting a new one up?

Comment: @Kuba exactly what I wanted, thank you very much!

Comment: @GaloisFan here are some starting points: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Stylesheets.html and http://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflowguide/StylingAndFormatting.html