# How to programmatically remove menu items

Tags: front-end

I would like to do the opposite of what is described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/907/how-do-i-add-new-menuitems-to-menus). So rather than add a menu item I would like to programmatically remove one (or more). So given a knowledge of the structure of the menu *.tr file

[image]

...I am looking for something like `RemoveMenuCommands` such that if I wanted to remove **Format > Clear Formatting** I could enter something like this:

```
FrontEndExecute[RemoveMenuCommands[{"Format", "Clear Formatting"}]]
```

Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Good question. Could be extended to how to remove an installed palette as there is only an install menu and not an uninstall one. Removing a palette takes more than removing the menu item, though.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I find removing a palette ok thought would be nice if it could be done with an uninstall menu option. Removing a menu option requires file editing (at the moment)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WRI tech support advise that it is not currently possible to programmatically remove items from the menu.