# What is the syntax for adding code, e.g. LinkWrite[...] to init.m? Version 12.0

Tags: front-end, syntax, initialization, version-12

I'm trying to use the suggestions for adding menu items discussed here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/909/44139

When I add ...

```
LinkWrite[$ParentLink, 
 AddMenuCommands[
  "BackgroundDialog", {Delimiter, 
   Item["M&y Color", Background -> RGBColor[0.980, 0.941, 0.902]]}]]
```

To $UserBaseDirectory\FrontEnd\init.m I get a startup error

> Could not process unknown packet "LinkWrite".

In a notebook, the command executes and adds the menu item.  It's been a long time since I tried to hack the init.m.  I've forgotten how.  Any suggestions?

---

Edit:
With the help of the comments, I concluded that the suggestion I was attempting to implement is not a good solution to my problem.  Instead I copied

```
$InstallationDirectory\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\TextResources\Windows\MenuSetup.tr
```

to

```
$UserBaseDirectory\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\TextResources\Windows\MenuSetup.tr
```

,adding the necessary directories.  I then modified the copy, which Mathematica prioritizes over the original.

I'm not sure what to do about this question, since it might be useful to someone else;  even if the answer is "Don't do that!"

Comment: It's a tricky business talking to the front end during kernel initialization, you might have better luck wrapping the call in `RunScheduledTask`

Comment: Couple of things.  1.)  The FrontEnd's init.m is for preferences, not arbitrary expressions.  It is frequently overwritten.  The Kernel's init.m is a safer place to put items like this.  2.)  I would not recommend writing arbitrary expressions to links you did not open/manage.   I would probably recommend using FrontEndExecute[] after checking $Notebooks is True.